# Invalid index error using azure terraform - terraform-azurerm-dns-recordsets

Tags: azure, terraform

I try to deploy dns terraform using below code.

```
    main.tf

    module "dns_records" {
      source              = "https://github.com/terraformdns/terraform-azurerm-dns-recordsets.git"
      resource_group_name = var.rg_name
      dns_zone_name       = azurerm_dns_zone.main.name
      recordsets          = var.recordsets
    }
```

```
    prod.tfvars

    recordsets = [{
      name    = "membersinfo"
      type    = "MX"
      ttl     = 3600
      records = ["10 reply", "20 mail",]
    }]
```

I am getting the below error. Not found any solution yet.

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/dns_records/main.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_dns_mx_record" "this":
│   96:       exchange   = split(record.value, " ")[1]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ record.value is "10 reply"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/dns_records/main.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_dns_mx_record" "this":
│   96:       exchange   = split(record.value, " ")[1]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ record.value is "20 mail"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.
```

According to https://github.com/terraformdns/terraform-azurerm-dns-recordsets
Running code as is should create dns-zone and add dns entries. A and CNAME records added ok. But MX and spf failing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out its an error from split function using terraform 1.5.x

terraform module above references defined `split(record.value, " ")` but this should be `split(" ", record.value)`